# How do we know that a transaction has been canceled?

Tags: fantom

For example,

If I see this

https://ftmscan.com/tx/0xa491250e25eb3511d6313f662662eb8e10b07d8fb033f81516dce41d97adcda3

It's written

that there is this contract

https://ftmscan.com/tx/0x29379361935e319e164df35f32439b4d1de9cc2087ac1338f0b96a5ca3382663 like 32 days ago

And that the contract is self destruct

https://ftmscan.com/address/0x7c1a0ef4c0e8fcfa871a8ef7617ed2ccd2e838af

What about this transaction?

https://ftmscan.com/tx/0x3dba04ddf34a4c59b62fd7923cc568958de77ac6dffc9feb13092f056f9b2372

Is it canceled? Is it destructed?

How do I know?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean -> what happened to the transactions sent to destructed contract after/before destruct?

Comment: I want to know if a transaction is self destructed or not. Is it a contract that can be self destructed or a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when self destruct is called on a contract, nothing happens to transactions prior to that. They're set in stone.

Self destruct takes one argument, the address to send all the contract's funds to, so any funds held at the contract address will go to wherever was decided by the self destruct caller.

Any funds sent to the contract's address after self destruct are either stuck there as no one knows the private key for the address, or could be retrieved if the contract was deployed with create2 and was again deployed to that same address.